# features:uninstall -v or features:uninstall --verbose is not showing what is being done in Karaf 2.4.0.redhat-630310

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I am using Jboss fuse 6.3 and one of my features file when trying to uninstall throwing TimeoutException  (below mentioned is detail). This features has one bundle which is communicate with service cloud using camel steaming API.

I wanted to see what Karaf is uninstalling when ran  features:uninstall -v  . But Karaf is showing only 
Uninstalling feature . Any suggestion, how can we see what Karaf is trying to uninstall and where it is stuck to get timeout exception.

Any idea suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.doInvokeAny(AbstractExecutorService.java:184)[:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAny(AbstractExecutorService.java:225)[:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper$4.call(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:184)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper$15.call(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:452)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.RWLock.runReadOperation(RWLock.java:35)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.runUnlessShutdown(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:447)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.invokeAny(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:178)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher.callListener(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher.callListeners(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:189)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher.blueprintEvent(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.destroy(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:897)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender$3.run(BlueprintExtender.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_144]

Comment: There seams to be ordering issue when stopping camel. You can get a thread dump by invoking `jstack -l <pid-of-Fuse>` that may show more details. Also, without knowing which feature you're uninstalling I can't deduce much.

Comment: Did you check fuse log?

Comment: @Alessandro Da Rugna ,Thank you for asking but  Fuse log is only showing java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException which I added. I tried with fuse log:set DEBUG and still not getting anything in log. After all I asked help from forum

Comment: If you list all the bundles (`list -t 0` or something similar, I don't remember the exact command) do you see any bundle being deactivated? This can give a hint

Comment: no all the bundle are up and running